# Want to sum of each start time and end time in an array in laravel and want to get the difference between the end time and start time

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Want to sum of each start time and end time and get the difference between sum of endtime and start time in laravel

```
[
  {
    "id": 108172,
    "qc_id": 1319,
    "audit_id": 104132,
    "start_time": "11:1:49",
    "end_time": "11:1:52"
  },
  {
    "id": 108191,
    "qc_id": 1319,
    "audit_id": 104132,
    "start_time": "11:2:3",
    "end_time": "11:13:26"
  },
  {
    "id": 108192,
    "qc_id": 1319,
    "audit_id": 104132,
    "start_time": "11:13:30",
    "end_time": "11:13:45"
  }
]
```

Explanation: All row start time, all row end time and after that calculate the difference between the `end_time - start_time`. How can we do this in laravel ?

I did this but did not get the response

```
$qc_audit_time_taken = QcAuditTimeTaken::where('audit_id', base64_decode($store_id))->get();

    $data = json_decode($qc_audit_time_taken, true);

    $startTimeSum = 0;
    $endTimeSum = 0;

    foreach ($data as $entry) {
        $startTimeParts = explode(':', $entry['start_time']);
        $endTimeParts = explode(':', $entry['end_time']);
        
        $startTimeSum += $startTimeParts[0] * 3600 + $startTimeParts[1] * 60 + $startTimeParts[2];
        $endTimeSum += $endTimeParts[0] * 3600 + $endTimeParts[1] * 60 + $endTimeParts[2];
    }

    // Calculate the difference between the sum of end times and start times
    $timeDifference = $endTimeSum - $startTimeSum;

    // Convert the time difference back to hours, minutes, and seconds
    $hours = floor($timeDifference / 3600);
    $minutes = floor(($timeDifference % 3600) / 60);
    $seconds = $timeDifference % 60;

echo "Time Difference: $hours hours, $minutes minutes, $seconds seconds";
```

Comment: _"I did this but did not get the response"_ - okay, so what exactly are you talking about? https://3v4l.org/q6Gol clearly produced a result - something _wrong_ about that now? ("Time Difference: 0 hours, 11 minutes, 41 seconds" looks about right, but I did not actually do the math to verify.) Or what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I want to take the sum of all the start time inside an array and sum of the all end time after that want to subtract the end time - start time. How can I do this (means sum of all start time and sum of all end time and the difference between the  end time and start time ?

Comment: I specifically asked you to explain what is (supposedly) wrong with the result your code is currently producing. Because in my opinion, it appears to be doing exactly what you are asking for. If the result of what you explained, with the given input data, is _not_ supposed to be `0 hours, 11 minutes, 41 seconds` - then explain what else you expected ...?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/nN9mQ  Issue has been now resolved